# Dynamic rewrite rules. Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, mod-rewrite

I have a strange task and I haven't worked with Tomcat yet, so don't beat me strongly.

I have an application written on node.js that generates random string every couple of minutes. After that, it should create rewrite rule for Apache Tomcat using the random string as a condition. The rule should make reverse proxy to the node.js app.

for Apache the rule would be like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(random_string/?(.*)?)$ http://localhost:8000/$1 [L,P]
</IfModule>
```

As I know there are two ways for making this:

- Tomcat 8 has own Valve for rewriting
- Tuckey URL filter

Help me please with this issues:

- What popularity of `Tuckey` and `valves.rewrite.RewriteValve`
- How to make config reload for Tomcat
- How to make proxy reverse using `valves.rewrite.RewriteValve`

UPD: 
Tuckey Url filter can reload class by param `confReloadCheckInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make config reload for Tomcat

I do not believe it is possible to reload the main configuration file like other services such as Apache HTTPD. This is taken from the docs:

[...since the main conf/server.xml file cannot be reloaded without restarting Tomcat.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context)

However, context can be reloaded so there is hope as the documents on RewriteValve indicate the following:

[... It can also be in the context.xml of a webapp.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html)

Hope that helps.